# Getting error JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter when importing from API

Tags: java, python, json, api

I am trying to parse response data from an API but I keep getting this error.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS776en-GB.json"

r = requests.get(url)
json_data = r.json()
```

This is the error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 889, in json
   return complexjson.loads(
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
   obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 233384 (char 233383)
```

I've confirmed this is a valid JSON and this is a public API so I don't have control over the formatting. How can I get past this error?

Comment: There IS an error in the json returned from the url - even Firefox is unable to display the url and complains with SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 233384 of the JSON data

Comment: There _is_ an error in JSON, according to jsonlint.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your code but the json.

You can validate json [here](https://jsonlint.com). Line 7669 and 7670 are missing a `,` each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS776en-GB.json"

r = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: Yeah, i just realised its not real json. This is a problem with the API, not the code. If you visit the api in Firefox, it will tell you the same thing.